# How to decorate code in C# wiithout C/C++ - like macros

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

C# does not support C/C++ macros. There are many Q&A related to this in StackOverflow but I couldn't find answer to specific question.

Let say I am using code like one suggested at http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html:

```
if(log.IsDebugEnabled) 
{
    log.Debug("Entry number: " + i + " is " + entry[i]);
}
```

This way to enable/disable logging has obvious drawbacks. In C++ I would use a macro like  LOG(expr) to improve code readability and to have better control on 'if(log.IsDebugEnabled)' part of code (which is probably repeated thousand times in a project).

How can I achieve LOG(expr) - like result in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try aspect oriented programming see [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging#).

Comment: Move IsDebugEnabled test to the logger Debug function.

Comment: And just because it might not be obvious from reading your question, what you're looking for is a way to toggle the logger on and off **at runtime**, and to ensure that the argument to `log.Debug` is not evaluated *at all* if logging is disabled, correct?

Comment: AOP in itself won't solve the problem of not executing computational expensive expressions when e.g., Debug is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use new log4net `XXXXFormat` methods instead. They are implemented this way:

```
public virtual void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args)
{
    if (this.IsDebugEnabled)
    {
       this.Logger.Log(declaringType, m_levelDebug, String.Format(format, args));
    }
}
```

Also you will have power of `String.Format` instead of simple concatenation of strings

```
log.DebugFormat("Entry number: {0} is {1}", i, entry[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this also can be a solution, although I dislike format. In my C++ code that uses log4cxx I use stream operations ( << ). So in C# my preference probably will be + (at the end of story I need to construct a single string to be written to logger)

Comment: @mvidelgauz in C# using `+` produces many strings in memory. I.e. `a + b + c + d` will produce `ab`, `abc`, and `abcd` strings. With `String.Format` working with strings is efficient and no additional strings created

Answer (score 3):

You can't.... Because C# doesn't have macros!

Of course you could do something like this instead:

Define log function which takes a lambda

```
void Log(Func<string> f) {
  if(log.IsDebugEnabled) 
  {
    log.Debug(f());
  }
}
```

and call it like this when you want to log something:

```
Log(()=>"Entry number: " + i + " is " + entry[i]);
```

This way, the argument is only evaluated if logging is enabled, which I assume is what you wanted to achieve.

(My C# is a bit rusty, so the syntax might be slightly off)

Comment: To prevent the argument from being evaluated if logging is disabled. Suppose you want to log the result of a very expensive function call. That very expensive function shouldn't be called if logging is disabled.

Comment: Ah ... I noticed the part of the documentation he is talking about now. _"If you are worried about speed"_ ... I didn't realize he was worried about speed.

Comment: Yeah, the question isn't entirely clear, but as I read it, he wants to be able to avoid evaluating the log expression entirely if logging is disabled, *and* have the ability to enable/disable logging at runtime

Comment: Should the call not be Log(()=>"Entry number: " + i + " is " + entry[i]);

Comment: @ilias Nah, it should be nameOfObject.Log(()=>"Entry number: " + i + " is " + entry[i]); because it isn't static.

Comment: Oops, fixed so the function at least has the same name when it's defined and called. Thanks @ilias

Comment: Thank you jalf for your answer! It is very useful reminder about lamdas for me! ))). And probably the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as a method and mark it as debugger conditional:

```
internal static SomeClass
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")] 
    internal static void Log(string expr)
    {
     //...
    }
}
```

The compiler will remove this method and any call or reference to this method if the compiler constant "DEBUG" is not defined. Yes, it works with others too. It is similar to:

```
internal static SomeClass
{
    #if DEBUG
    internal static void Log(string expr)
    {
     //...
    }
    #endif
}
```

But using that will not remove the references to this method, so you would have to wrap those too.

---

Yes, this only allows to disable log at compile time. [jalf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33213/jalf) has a [better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13064287/402022) to handle this at runtime.

Comment: Still relevant information since the OP's question isn't that clear.

Comment: Thank you Theraot! I didn't know about [Conditional("DEBUG")] and I'll try it. Will it eliminate unnecessarily code that constructs string argument? Jalf, I understand that this is a different approach, but also can be useful if I want to disable logging at compile time, right?

Comment: @mvidelgauz yes, anything you pass to a method with the Conditonal attribute will be removed by the compiler if it is only used there. This is done even without code optimization. PS: why not use string.Format?

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, you can create class with one static method, which will accept string expression.

Answer (score 0):

> ... part of code (which is probably **repeated** thousand times in a
>   project).

Whenever you are thinking something like that, the first thing that should pop up in your head is [encapsulate, encapsulate, encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)!

You could simply create your own Logger class which has a `IsDebugEnabled` property and your own `Log` method.

```
void Log( string message )
{
  if ( IsDebugEnabled ) 
  {
     log.Debug( message );
  }
}
```

Probably better to look around for existing logger libraries, which probably already support all the functionality you need.

E.g. [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: As I understand the question, this only solves half of the problem: he wants to be able to toggle logging at runtime (which your example allows), but *also* be able to avoid evaluating `message` at all if logging is disabled. (for example, say I call your function like this: `Log(expensiveFunction())`, and I don't want `expensiveFunction` to be called at all if logging is disabled. :)

Comment: Good point, I'll just keep this answer around here as yours already addresses that part. :) I'm sure the OP has plenty of information available now.

Answer (score -1):

Aspect-oriented programming is what you want, because things like logging and caching has little to do with your business logic. So they should be separated.

There are many frameworks available, take a look at postsharp(http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), or snap (http://www.simpleaspects.com/). If you use one of the supported dependency injection framework, maybe snap is good choice.

UPDATE: if you are using log4net, you should be able to turn it off from the config file, `<log4net threshold="OFF" />` So you should have a debug config and a release config

Comment: AOP is relevant, but not sure whether it would help out the OP in his particular scenario, then we'd need more information.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but having LOG() everywhere is just ugly and distracting. I would refactor and use aop.